# Update one column's value based on another column's value in Pandas using regular expression

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe like below:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Category':['Personal Care', 'Home Care', 'Pharma', 'Pet'], 'SubCategory':['Shampoo', 'Floor Wipe', 'Veterinary', 'Animal Feed']})
>>> df
        Category  SubCategory
0  Personal Care      Shampoo
1      Home Care   Floor Wipe
2         Pharma   Veterinary
3            Pet  Animal Feed
```

I'd like to update the value in 'Category' column whenever the 'Subcategory' column's value contains either 'Veterinary' or 'Animal' (case-insensitive). To do that, I devised a method like below:

```
def update_col1_values_based_on_values_in_col2_using_regex_mappings(
            df,
            col1_name: str,
            col2_name: str,
            dictionary_of_regex_mappings: dict):
        for pattern, new_str_value in dictionary_of_regex_mappings.items():
            mask = df[col2_name].str.contains(pattern)
            df.loc[mask, col1_name] = new_str_value

        return df
```

This method works as expected as shown below:

```
>>> df1 = update_col1_values_based_on_values_in_col2_using_regex_mappings(df, 'Category', 'SubCategory', {"(?i).*Veterinary.*": "Pet Related", "(?i).*Animal.*": "Pet Related"})

>>> df1
        Category  SubCategory
0  Personal Care      Shampoo
1      Home Care   Floor Wipe
2    Pet Related   Veterinary
3    Pet Related  Animal Feed
```

In practice, there will be more than 'Veterinary' and 'Animal Feed' to map from, so some of the suggestions below, although they read elegant, are not going be practical for the actual use case. In other words, please assume that the mapping is going to be more like this:

```
{
"(?i).*Veterinary.*": "Pet Related", 
"(?i).*Animal.*": "Pet Related"
"(?i).*Pharma.*": "Pharmaceutical",
"(?i).*Diary.*": "Other",
... # lots and lots more mapping here
}
```

I'm wondering if there's a more elegant (Pandas-ish) way to accomplish this. Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

EDIT: I didn't clarify in the beginning that the mapping between 'Category' and 'Subcategory' columns wouldn't be restricted to just 'Veterinary' and 'Animal'.

Comment: you could build a dict and pass it to .replace

Comment: `df.loc[df.SubCategory.str.contains('Veterinary|Animal',flags = re.IGNORECASE),'Category']='Pet Related'
` ?

Comment: @Chris, how would you go about that? I actually tried `replace`, but it copies values from 'SubCategory' to 'Category' column if the regex matching fails. E.g., df['Category'] = df['SubCategory'].replace({"(?i).*Veterinary.*": "Pet Related", "(?i).*Animal.*": "Pet Related"}, regex=True) replaces the original values, 'Personal Care' and 'Home Care' from 'Category' column to 'Shampoo' and 'Floor Wipe'. Any suggestion on how to use `replace` to make `update_col1_values_based_on_values_in_col2_using_regex_mappings` method tidier would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code, which is intuitive.

```
df['Category'] = df['SubCategory'].map(lambda x: "Pet Related" if "Animal" in x or "Veterinary" in x else x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the mapping is not just restricted to two categories in practice (i.e. I will have to map about 100 items from one column to the next), so this elegant (which I agree) approach is not going to fare well.

Comment: you can have a separate function that maintains this mapping logic and invoke that on variable x inside map.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with [`pd.DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html), and `re` to add the flag case-insensitive:

```
import re
df.Category.where(~df.SubCategory.str.contains('Veterinary|Animal',flags = re.IGNORECASE),'Pet Related',inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
        Category  SubCategory
0  Personal Care      Shampoo
1      Home Care   Floor Wipe
2    Pet Related   Veterinary
3    Pet Related  Animal Feed
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the mapping is not just restricted to two categories in practice (i.e. I will have to map about 100 items from one column to the next), so this elegant (which I agree) approach is not going to fare well.

Comment: Could you add a sample of the original dataframe? @user1330974

Comment: The data is quite big and the mappings are growing. I pasted a sample of recent data here (not sure if SO moderators would remove the link, but I don't know the appropriate way to share sample data via SO): https://pastebin.com/zrYxRTnX
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you can do this:

```
df.loc[df.SubCategory.str.contains('Veterinary|Animal'), 'Category']='Pet Related'
```

If you need to use regex, str.contains() does also support regex

```
pattern = r'(?i)veterinary|animal'
df.loc[df.SubCategory.str.contains(pattern, regex=True), 'Category']='Pet Related'
```

And this is the result

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        Category  SubCategory
0  Personal Care      Shampoo
1      Home Care   Floor Wipe
2    Pet Related   Veterinary
3    Pet Related  Animal Feed
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but the mapping is not just restricted to two categories in practice (i.e. I will have to map about 100 items from one column to the next), so this elegant (which I agree) approach is not going to fare well